# get value from 'terms' table

Tags: database, terms

so I feel like I am missing something very obvious, but I need to get a value from the database table 'terms', and it seems get_terms fetches from taxonomy table. I've tried get_term_by as well but to no avail.

I could simply build a regular request and get the data needed, no worries. But I feel like I must be missing something obvious, as it has to be a regular occurance among wordpress users to fetch data from that table.

/Regards
Sonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_terms` does indeed fetch from the terms table, but it does also use a join on the taxonomy table, since you need to specify which taxonomies you want terms for in your `get_terms` query.

If you want to get *all* terms, you could use something like:

```php
$all_terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => get_taxonomies(),
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
```